# Какая разница между словами "времени" и "время"?

Tags: лексика, словообразование, выбор-слов

В каком случае "времени" и "время" равнозначны?

Бенджамин Франклин сказал: *"Любишь ты жизнь? Тогда не теряй **времени**; ибо **время** — ткань, из которой состоит жизнь"*.

Мне непонятно, почему он повторял "время" после "времени"? Разница между ними контекстуальна?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

1. Слово одно и тоже.

Им. п. (что?) — время; р. п (нет чего?) — времени; д. п. (подошли к чему?) — ко времени; в.п. (вижу что?) — время; т. п. (доволен чем?) — временем; п. п. (говорили о чем?) — о времени.

Не теряй (чего?) времени. Род. падеж.

2. Повторять, подчёркивать то есть, или уходить от повтора (могло бы быть «ибо оно — ткань») определяет автор.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое  за помощь)))